# Integer is required (got type str): using ipyparallel and jupyter

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I'm trying to get ipyparallel working. I'm following the [Getting Stared guide](http://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) but the basic functionality isn't working on my machine.

I launch a cluster from the command line

```
ipcluster start -n 4
```

and then I run the script:

```
 import ipyparallel as ipp
 c=ipp.Client()
 print(c[:].apply_sync(lambda : "Hello, World"))
```

In Python3, it works as expected, but not when run in Python2. I get the error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Also, when I run the snippet in a Jupyter notebook, using both python 2 and 3 kernels, I get the same error.

Any ideas why I'm getting this error? Thanks.

---

### Edit:

The total error in jupyter is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipyparallel/serialize/serialize.py in unpack_apply_message(bufs, g, copy)
    185     assert len(bufs) >= 2, "not enough buffers!"
    186     pf = buffer_to_bytes_py2(bufs.pop(0))
--> 187     f = uncan(pickle.loads(pf), g)
    188     pinfo = buffer_to_bytes_py2(bufs.pop(0))
    189     info = pickle.loads(pinfo)
~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipyparallel/serialize/codeutil.py in code_ctor(*args)
     22 
     23 def code_ctor(*args):
---> 24     return types.CodeType(*args)
     25 
     26 def reduce_code(co):
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I'm using Python3.5.2 and Python2.7.12, with ipyparallel v6.0.2. I've seen somewhere that ipyparallel v6 doesn't required >Python3, though I can't see this in the [docs](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), so I'd be happy to get this working only for Python3.

Comment: Is there any stack trace? Are you using a stable version? If not, isn't it a known issue in the project's tracker?

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the question to include the total error given in the Jupyter notebook. and the versions. I don't think it's a known issue, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was I hadn't enabled clusters in jupyter. In the terminal, I ran

```
sudo ipcluster nbextension enable
```

and opened jupyter notebook in the same terminal

```
jupyter notebook
```

and then it worked.

Note you may first need to

```
pip install notebook ipyparallel
```

Also see [this page](https://github.com/ipython/ipyparallel) for using `ipcluster` in jupyter.